# Error (Xcode): Unknown option: -Xlinker (Flutter on MacOS)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, linker

Getting this error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           22.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Unknown option: -Xlinker

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
```

the build fails when running from Android Studio.
the app works fine on running from xcode.
i am using xcode 15.0
the below is the "Podfile" file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Also tried upgrading flutter to latest stable version 3.13.9
still the issue persists
Also, commenting and uncommenting the "use_frameworks!" line does not help.

Also Flutter doctor -v says "No issues found!".

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-x64, locale
    en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.13.7 on channel stable at
      /Users/nitinsaraswat/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2f708eb839 (3 weeks ago), 2023-10-09 09:58:08 -0500
    • Engine revision a794cf2681
    • Dart version 3.1.3
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/nitinsaraswat/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.28.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/nitinsaraswat/Applications/Visual Studio
      Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro (mobile) • 1CF59B04-70B6-48F3-95AB-EC6C0936AA6A • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-x64
      • macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.117

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

i am facing this issue in Flutter Sample Counter app.
not using any dependencies.
Here's the link to the [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jGG5a4m6LqYw3dAin_7zWmIp2znbfs76/view?usp=sharing)
There is also a github issue opened for the same problem.
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137250).

i am expecting that "flutter run" command should work.